# Showing image from different project ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h3>Single Upload</h3>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File <input type="file" name="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="return SaveExit()" />
</form>
<img src="C:/Users/Gigabyte/source/repos/ReimbursementSystem/ReimbursementSystemAPI/wwwroot/Images/biomimikrifix1.png" width="100" height="200" alt="3"  />
```

I want to simply show the image from the other project with the path but it doesn't work. is there a way to simply show it from another project?

Comment: You should be hosting your projects in a web server, then you can use web api or direct url to retrieve the image.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net Core MVC you are **not allowed to load local resource file** rather than wwwroot/images folder by default. But if you want to use a different location then you can simply add this middleware to your startup.cs

### Startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Gigabyte\source\repos\ReimbursementSystem\ReimbursementSystemAPI\wwwroot", "images")),
            RequestPath = "/images"
        });
```

### cshtml

```
<img src="/Images/biomimikrifix1.png" width="100" height="200" alt="3"/>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<img src="/Images/biomimikrifix1.png" width="100" height="200" alt="3" class="detailImage"  />
```